# Unit test Material UI styles

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a styles written in JavaScript file that are Material UI styles and I want to unit test them

I tried to export and unit test but it didn't work.

```
const styles = () => ({});
```

How to unit test the above code?

Comment: `expect(styles()).toEqual({})`? What value is there in unit testing this?

Comment: in styles there will be styles written and called within styles

Comment: Yes, but it's generally all static data that doesn't actually alter any *behaviour*.

Comment: not working, I am trying hard :(

Comment: Then give a [mcve], it's impossible to say from what you've posted what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex'
  }
})

I want to write a unit test case for the above code snippet. How to do? My component name is RadioButton

Comment: 1. [Edit] the question. 2. What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? 3. Why would it matter what the component name is in terms of testing this function?

Comment: Yes, to test this function the component name is RadioButton

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions and you still haven't actually edited the post.